# Why does my bandpass filter act as highpass?

Tags: filter, passive-networks

I have designed a bandpass filter. Here is the circuit and spectral characteristic:

[image]

As you can see from the response curve, it has cutoff with the peak ranging from 260 kHz to 290 kHz.

Here is the actual circuit :

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, the filter works more like a High pass, passing frequencies all above 250 kHz, without any distortion or attenuation.

Here is one of the outputs :

[image]

(I observe outputs at all frequencies above 250 kHz. This is just one example)

Where am I going wrong, and what corrections do I need to make?

Update :

I decided to simulate my circuit , and it was clear why my circuit acted as Highpass. (The last freq is graph in 1 MHz). Dunno why the filter design tool showed that (incorrect) graph then.

[image]

Comment: It's tough to say if the filter is behaving correctly without seeing the ratio of the output signal to the input signal. Don't expect the higher frequency signals to disappear altogether, they will be subject to attenuation which will depend on how far their frequency is from the passband, and the order of the filter.

Comment: @clabacchio . But it is passing the signals even in the passband with same amplitude ( in fact a little lesser !)

Comment: Can you add a picture showing how you constructed the circuit?

Comment: I won't do the math, but what are the tolerances on your passive elements, and how does that bubble through your frequency response?

Comment: @ScottSeidman . Frankly speaking, i'm a noob at filter design and I only know basics. So i am basically relying on software tools only to get a filter for my project work. And the tolerances are 5% for all.

Comment: @ThePhoton . I have added the pics and have tried my best to show it from different angles.

Comment: I suspect that the parasitic capacitance of the inductors and/or the parasitic inductance of the capacitors may be the source of the problem.

Comment: Just asking because inductors of that sizer are more typically 20% or even 30% devices.

Comment: @ScottSeidman . My apologies. The inductors are 10%. I mistook yellow color top band for gold.

Comment: What DC resistance does each inductor have? Add that resistance in series with each inductor, and re-simulate. Compare with measurement... Parasitic capacitances and inductances may have tiny effects (the top taps are 1nf, which is huge!) but I suspect this is the main culprit. Indeed if you replace the inductors with resistors you have a classic high pass filter...

Comment: The resistor at the end of the filter doesn't appear to be in parallel to the last inductor/capacitor pair.  Could you confirm the wiring of that 50Ohm resistor?

Comment: @Jre . According to schematic, the last resistor is in parallel ; its attached with the last capacitor and inductor pair. Brian, I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @Plutonium smuggler Ah.. I see my problem.  The filter is built backwards from the way I would have expected - the output end is closest to the generator rather than being farthest away.  That explains it.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @BrianDrummond . I used the multimeter to measure DC resistance . I suspect it is too small to show up (Multimeter can measure 1 milli Ohms). What now ?

Comment: Look at your bode of the simulation, particularly the Y-axis.  You still expect 30-40 dB of attenuation at high frequency, and you ain't seeing it!

Answer (score 1):

With the photos, I'd venture that you have stray capacitances all over your circuit because it is on a solderless breadboard.  You shouldn't be doing high frequency work like this on one of those.  Of course, this doesn't rule out parasitic effects addressed in the comments to your question, but there is a gorilla in the room, and it's the breadboard.

Comment: If not breadboard, then what else can I use ?

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler  Solder it down to a perforated prototyping breadboard, something like http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/DMB-4770-CB/377-2076-ND/3829629

Comment: Are you sure prototyping on breadboard will create problems ? Because I dont really know soldering ( I have planned to solder once my design works on breadboard ; and besides I have only limited components, both in variety and quantity)

Comment: http://www.eevblog.com/forum/blog/eevblog-568-solderless-breadboard-capacitance/  -- I'll leave it to you to do the math, but you have 2.5 puff capacitances across every connection at a megahertz. As an aside, you're getting answers about why your passive filter isn't working, but if you really need to get the job done, you should consider an active filter.

Comment: Well, my filter wasnt working because that filter design tool was stupid ; I spent days refining the design, and now I find that the response curve it generated was incorrect.

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler -- as I suggested as a comment to your edit, be careful there.  The bode you posted still show QUITE A GOOD DEAL of attenuation at high freqs, like 40 dB.

Answer (score 0):

Filter designs often require a very small component tolerance. So normally, your filter will not work as expected if you just use standard 1% or 5% tolerance components.

Try to simulate the filter again with some of the component values slightly altered -- has this much impact on the frequency response curve?